# Create a proxy to a function with many overloads in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have a problem with the following code when trying to create a proxy to a function with many overloads:

```js
// The function to proxy
function original (a: number): boolean;
function original (a: string): boolean;
function original (a: boolean): boolean;

function original (a: number | string | boolean): boolean {
  return true;
}

// The proxy
function pass (a: string | number){
  return original(a); // here
};

pass(5);
pass('a');
pass(true);
```

When trying to create a proxy to the `original` function TS throw me the following error :

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(a: number): boolean', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(a: string): boolean', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
      Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  Overload 3 of 3, '(a: boolean): boolean', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'boolean'.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.(2769)
input.tsx(5, 10): The call would have succeeded against this implementation, but implementation signatures of overloads are not externally visible.
```

Few things to know about this :

- I reduced my bug to this minimal situation where the problem happens
- The `pass(true)` call return an error, so typing seems to work for the `pass` function
- In my situation, the `original` function is from a module, so if any situation exist without modifications on it would be perfect

Here is a [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABHATjA5jMBDANogCmwC5EwQBbAIwFMUBKUquOXG7MAbgFgAoUSLATI0mHPiKkAzlDRh0jRM1bsufAdHhJUGLHkIklLNh0XKTa3uvCbhOsfsllKtFIgA%20iGXPQejK0yZjVUQAbz5ERBQaKBAUJFkQGh5eAF8%20a0EtRAAHbCkpA2lZLF9Pcmo6enDeSOjY%20JFdcSJ6TkQAeg7EKAALGEK6FFQ%20VJS%20PIKCAFY2ifypAgBybCW53knFxJo2oA) with the previous code.

Answer (score 1):

If getting rid of the error is your objective, then checking the type before calling the original function will get rid of the error.

```js
function pass (a: string | number){
  if (typeof a === "number") {
    return original(a);
  } else if(typeof a === "string"){
    return original(a);
  }
  throw new Error(`Expected string or number`);
};
```

Comment: Thank you, that's the answer. I would have liked to dodge this solution but as mentioned [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#writing-good-overloads): **TypeScript can only resolve a function call to a single overload**.

Answer (score 0):

Just cast it to needed type

```
function original(a: number): boolean;
function original(a: string): boolean;
function original(a: boolean): boolean;

function original(a: number | string | boolean): boolean {
  return true;
}

const pass = original as (a: string | number) => boolean

pass(5);
pass('a');
pass(true);
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=15&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABHATjA5jMBDANgCmwC5EwQBbAIwFMUBKEyuOXa7MAbgFgAoUSWAmRpMOAsUQBnKGjDoGiJizade-aPCSoMWPIUbNW7BUqOqea8BqHbReiWSq1EAHykys6V4sMqTv9kQAb15ERBRqKBAUJBkQam4eAF9eXggEaUQAB2xJSUQAXmEdMURcxH13WS83Rxp6QoA+H2V2VJ4cvPwAVjpEzsl8AHJsIb7eAfw46nGLHiA